# How to "svn export" a remote branch on github?

Tags: git, deployment, branch

I do not need any history, I just want the files from the said branch to be downloaded locally .

This is for a deploy script

```
 Usage: ./deploy.sh remote_branch_name
```

the script checks out an arbitrary branch from a remote github repository and copies the files to a server.

I figured I could use git clone without history:

```
git clone --depth 1 your_repo_url
```

But how can I specify a branch to checkout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-b` flag with clone:

> --branch `<name>`
>   -b `<name>`
>
> Instead of pointing the newly created HEAD to the branch pointed to
>   by the cloned repository's HEAD, point to  branch instead. In a
>   non-bare repository, this is the branch that will be checked out.

You might also want to explore the downloads that github provides for your repo.

On github, download links are available like so:

https://github.com/username/reponame/zipball/branch

Comment: oh, the -b flag wasn't available on my version of git.  I updated and now i see it.  But heck, the download link is EVEN BETTER!  That's what I want.  Thanks.  Now the question is... how do I run command to download programmatically. wget seems to fail repeatedly: Operation timed out.

Comment: oh... it might be because it's a private repo, i may have to add authentication credentials to download it